# System.Environment.OSVersion does not work on ASP.NET core application

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

I'm developing an ASP.NET Core application with VisualStudio 2018. In the app, System.Environment.OSVersion returns 6.2.9200.0 on Windows 10 PC. How to get accurate OS version number?

The net says it is because the application is not manifested, and you can add "Application Manifest File" from the Solution Explorer. However no such item is found. I found it in another .NET Framework application. It guess it was not there because ASP.NET CORE application does not support it.

Then I created a manifest file in another .NET Framework application, and transplanted into my ASP.NET Core application. The project's property recognized the manifest file.

Now my manifest file is like this. However OSVersion still returns 6.2.9200.0.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<assembly manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <assemblyIdentity version="1.0.0.0" name="KMS.app"/>
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
        <requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />
      </requestedPrivileges>
    </security>
  </trustInfo>

  <compatibility xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:compatibility.v1">
    <application>
      <!-- Windows Vista -->
      <!--<supportedOS Id="{e2011457-1546-43c5-a5fe-008deee3d3f0}" />-->

      <!-- Windows 7 -->
      <supportedOS Id="{35138b9a-5d96-4fbd-8e2d-a2440225f93a}" />

      <!-- Windows 8 -->
      <!--<supportedOS Id="{4a2f28e3-53b9-4441-ba9c-d69d4a4a6e38}" />-->

      <!-- Windows 8.1 -->
      <!--<supportedOS Id="{1f676c76-80e1-4239-95bb-83d0f6d0da78}" />-->

      <!-- Windows 10 -->
      <supportedOS Id="{8e0f7a12-bfb3-4fe8-b9a5-48fd50a15a9a}" />

    </application>
  </compatibility>
</assembly>
```

Comment: Have you had a look at https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet/issues/351 ?

Comment: I'm curious why you're even bothering to do this. Why does your application need to know what version of Windows it's hosted on?

Comment: Our target is Linux but some developers need to use Windows to test and develop. Some use Windows 7 and others use Windows 10. While Windows 10 can run a docker on your local, Windows 7 needs a VM to run a docker. It changes IP address for the servers running on your local. We have 100+ developers in my company and the app needs to switch it automatically.

Comment: Thank you, mjwills. Microsoft.DotNet.PlatformAbstractions.RuntimeEnvironment.OperatingSystemVersion works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [this link](https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet/issues/351#issuecomment-289313440), it is recommended that you use the `Microsoft.DotNet.PlatformAbstractions` package and the `Microsoft.DotNet.PlatformAbstractions.RuntimeEnvironment.OperatingSystemVersion` property to get this value.